# Axios AJAX запрос

Tags: ajax, post, axios

есть ли возможность сэмулировать корректный AJAX запрос?

```
        axios.post('php/data.php', {
            act: 'load'
        })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

данные можно получить через

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

а я хочу через $_POST получить данные

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем вопрос: другой сахар использовать?

Comment: дак это не сахар а дефолт как по мне

Answer (score 1):

import axios from 'axios';

```
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-TOKEN";
```

На принимающем сервере нужно поставить настройку:

```
    CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XCSRF-TOKEN"
```

Comment: axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

Comment: про сервер не понял

Comment: У Вас есть Backend Server, которые раздает данные по REST ?
На этом сервере есть возможность настраивать CSRF_COOKIE_NAME 
Эту настройку нужно установить в значение "XCSRF-TOKEN"

Comment: для yii2 где это сделать тогда?